# error when i run php artisan migrate command on line 51

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

**When I run the php artisan migrate command in terminal I'm left with this.**

```
   ParseError 

  syntax error, unexpected ')'

  at C:\laragon\www\testnum2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider.php:51
     47▕             return new DatabaseBatchRepository(  
     48▕                 $app->make(BatchFactory::class), 
     49▕                 $app->make('db')->connection(config('queue.batching.database')),
     50▕                 config('queue.batching.table', 'job_batches'),
  ➜  51▕             );
     52▕         });
     53▕     }
     54▕
     55▕     /**

  1   C:\laragon\www\testnum2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:322
      Composer\Autoload\includeFile("C:\laragon\www\testnum2\vendor\composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/BusServiceProvider.php")

  2   [internal]:0
      Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass("Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider")
PS C:\laragon\www\testnum2>
```

**I'm not quite sure what is causing but this is the code for that file thats causing the error.**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Bus;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher as QueueingDispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory as QueueFactoryContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BusServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Dispatcher::class, function ($app) {
            return new Dispatcher($app, function ($connection = null) use ($app) {
                return $app[QueueFactoryContract::class]->connection($connection);
            });
        });

        $this->registerBatchServices();

        $this->app->alias(
            Dispatcher::class, DispatcherContract::class
        );

        $this->app->alias(
            Dispatcher::class, QueueingDispatcherContract::class
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the batch handling services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerBatchServices()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(BatchRepository::class, DatabaseBatchRepository::class);

        $this->app->singleton(DatabaseBatchRepository::class, function ($app) {
            return new DatabaseBatchRepository(
                $app->make(BatchFactory::class),
                $app->make('db')->connection(config('queue.batching.database')),
                config('queue.batching.table', 'job_batches'),
            );
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            Dispatcher::class,
            DispatcherContract::class,
            QueueingDispatcherContract::class,
            BatchRepository::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

I hope that this is enough to get help.
I wanna also mention that I've used php artisan migrate before and recently I had to upgrade some things like composer and phpmyadmin

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: Mostly likely It's trailing comma in the function call: `config('queue.batching.table', 'job_batches'),` and you have php 7.2 (or older), where is was not yet allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the PHP version you're using ( below 7.3 ) does not support trailing comma in function calls.

Please read this: [Trailing Commas are allowed in Calls](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.trailing-commas)

Solution is to switch to `> PHP 7.3`

Comment: is there a reason for the comma. it works when i deleted the comma. So just for confirmation this wont cause in problems in the future right?

Comment: you are not supposed to change anything in `vendor` directory. because one single update can break your entire site, because your change won't be there. I'd suggest you to use php7.3 or use laravel 7 instead.

Comment: when i ran <?php phpinfo() ?> it showed up as PHP 7.4.11. im not that experienced so is it possible that i downloaded the wrong one. it was php-7.4.11-Win32-vc15-x64.zip on the official site

Comment: @MuamarCollins that's strange. if you're using php7.4 then you shouldn't have had that issue.

Comment: yea, do you think maybe its a problem with phpmyadmin or something. I may just reinstall laragon and then i can probably pin point what exactly it is. i didnt have this problem before updating that.

Comment: there are different versions on your system, and the CLI and the webserver can have different configurations

Answer (score 1):

**Well my problem was my PHP being <7.3**

**But when I simply checked it in phpinfo file it showed up as 7.4.11.**

@lagbox helped me by saying : *"there are different versions on your system, and the CLI and the webserver can have different configurations"*

To be honest I wasn't sure exactly what to do from that but **I decided to just delete PHP 7.2 from my PATH**.

- My hope was that it would then recognize I was using 7.4 and to my suprise it did.
- Also I'm sure there are more effective ways of doing this but that was the way I chose.